# запятая при сложных союзах

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, учебное-задание

"В случае оставления жалобы без последствий, к чему, по мнению адвоката, надо быть готовым, т.к. кассационные поводы очень слабы, партия каторжных, в числе которых была Маслова, могла отправиться в первых числах июня, и потому() для того, чтобы приготовиться к поездке за Масловой в Сибирь, что было твердо решено Нехлюдовым, надо было теперь же съездить по деревням, чтобы устроить там свои дела."

Объясните, пожалуйста, это странное сочетание "и потому для того, чтобы" . Почему после "потому" не ставится запятая? Я думала, что "потому" относится к "надо съездить по деревням", а "для того чтобы приготовиться к поездке", как бы внутри этого предложения, но тогда  знак нужен?

Answer (score 1):

[потому́](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/223133)
I. ***нареч.*** обстоят. причины
По этой причине, вследствие этого.

Здесь слово "потому" является наречием — после него запятая не ставится, его можно даже изъять из предложения или заменить синонимичным наречием.

Для понимания немного "упростимся":
...партия каторжных могла отправиться в первых числах июня, и [*почему?* — потому, поэтому, по этой причине, вследствие этого, вот почему] для того, чтобы приготовиться к поездке за Масловой в Сибирь, надо было теперь же съездить по деревням...

P. S. В цитате точка ставится после кавычек; "так как" в цитате сокращать нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

...**и потому для того**, чтобы приготовиться к поездке за Масловой в Сибирь, что было твердо решено Нехлюдовым, **надо было теперь же съездить по деревням,** чтобы устроить там свои дела.

ДЛЯ ТОГО ЧТОБЫ — составной подчинительный союз, который в данном случае **расчленяется запятой**, его местоименная часть включается в главное предложение.

Расчленению союза способствует наречие ***потому***.

§ 118. Расчленение сложного союза обязательно:
а) при наличии **слов, примыкающих к первой части союза** и логически выделяющих ее: при употреблении отрицания, усилительных, ограничительных и других частиц, вводных слов, **наречий.** Все эти слова перетягивают ударение на первую часть союза, способствуя переходу его в соотносительное слово:  И солнце как будто светит **только затем, чтобы** перед ее взором, не исчезая, сияло окно с неподвижным черным силуэтом (Фед.);

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134